# Rally: Unable to update custom field using Java

Tags: rally

I am trying to update a custom field on test case, here's my code:

```
JsonObject update_story = new JsonObject();
update_story.addProperty("c_UTMSURI",url); //url is a string
UpdateRequest updateReq = new UpdateRequest(ref,update_story);
try{
        UpdateResponse response = rest.update(update);
        return (response.wasSuccessful());      
    }
catch(Exception e){
        String errorMsg = "Caught exception while updating external ID for "+ref+"\n More Details "+e.getMessage();
        Logger.Log(errorMsg);
        System.out.println(errorMsg);
        return false;
    }
```

I am confused because this code was working fine till a couple of days back and now the script just breaks and gets me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/util/List;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @nickm . The problem was that my tool was adding another lbapi jar file on run time. This was causing the problem. The update goes through now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If these are the external jars that you have:

```
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
rally-rest-api-2.0.4.jar
```

this list matches what I have in my project. 
For example in Eclipse there are Access Rules for external libraries. If your IDE has something similar are there restrictions on access? This error may indicate a wrong version of httpclient library or some conflict.

Have you tested the following?

- different value for the same custom field, e.g. Rally host url, as in the code below.
- other custom fields of type string
- other custom fields of any type
- any fields

I tried with the code below and a custom field of type string was updated successfully.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.UpdateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.UpdateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class CreateUpdateTC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


            String url = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "user@co.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String projectRef = "/project/12345";
            String applicationName = "create update test case";


        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(url),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   


        try {
            for (int i=0; i<1; i++) { 
                System.out.println("Creating a test case...");
                JsonObject newTC = new JsonObject();
                newTC.addProperty("Name", "some testcase");
                newTC.addProperty("Project", projectRef); 


                CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcase", newTC);
                CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);  
                if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {

                    System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));          

                    //Read tc
                    String tcRef = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                    System.out.println(String.format("\nReading test case %s...", tcRef));
                    //Update tc
                    JsonObject tcUpdate = new JsonObject();
                    tcUpdate.addProperty("c_CustomString", url);
                    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(tcRef,tcUpdate);
                    UpdateResponse updateResponse = restApi.update(updateRequest);
                    if (updateResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                        System.out.println("Successfully updated test case: " + newTC.get("Name") +
                                " CustomString: " + tcUpdate.get("c_CustomString"));
                    }
                    else {
                        String[] updateErrors;
                        updateErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                        System.out.println("Error");
                        for (int j=0; i<updateErrors.length;j++) {
                            System.out.println(updateErrors[j]);
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    String[] createErrors;
                    createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                    System.out.println("Error");
                    for (int j=0; i<createErrors.length;j++) {
                        System.out.println(createErrors[j]);
                    }
                }
            }

        } finally {
            //Release all resources
            restApi.close();
        }   

}
```

}